# How to configure Automapper to convert string to array of any type?

Tags: c#, automapper

I would like to introduce AutoMapper convention, that would map any string property to array property by splitting the string value using separator char.

```
public class A {
    public string Prop1 { get; set; }
}

public class B {
    public MyEnum[] Prop1 { get; set; }
}

public enum MyEnum {
    Val1
}

 config.CreateMap<A, B>();
 var a = new A { Prop1 = "Val1" };
 var b = mapper.Map<B>(a);
```

I currently configure type conversion of each array type, e.g.:

```
c.CreateMap<string, MyEnum[]>()
    .ConvertUsing(value => value.Split(',', StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
         .Select(v => v.Trim())
         .Select(v => Enum.Parse<MyEnum>(v))
         .ToArray());
```

But I would like to make it more generic, so that it would be able to convert:

```
 - string => string[]
 - string => int[]
 - string => AnyEnum[]
```

Comment: you'd have to write some methods to perform these conversions, let's say custom converters, 
1 - converting the string to an array (you've done it already)
2 - converting the string to an array of int (split and parse, if parsing fails on a single item fail the conversion)
3 - Get the type of enum in converter `EnumConverter<T>` and do `Enum.Parse`

Comment: take a look at Custom Converters here
http://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Custom-type-converters.html

Comment: @Aarif: I have written `EnumConverter<T>`, but then I need to manually register the converter for each enum, e.g.  `config.CreateMap<string, MyEnum[]>().ConvertUsing<EnumConverter<MyEnum>>();`

Comment: use reflection and scan all enums and create a custom attribute if you want to skip certain Enums,

this might help https://stackoverflow.com/a/36415849/6027876

Comment: I don't understand the basis of this question. You want to be able to convert a string to one of three types right? Then you **need** to define the conversion routines for each of them **somewhere**. You can 'use reflection' and 'custom converters' all you want, but what does it achieve?

Comment: https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/blob/6463d4811ebe1f6e9d5182c5a521ed757d7b7494/src/UnitTests/Mappers/CustomMapperTests.cs#L70